# highcharts different colors for selected columns

Tags: highcharts, typeerror

Is it possible to have different colors for different selected columns in highcharts?

Here's a sketch for what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jZmYW/4/

When selecting a point (column) it should get a specific color. I try to achieve that with setting new data for the selected point.
Visually it leads to the expected result but comes with a JS-error: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'setState' of object # is not a function".

I also tried to apply the functionality to the series (with setting new data there). That gives a quite similar result where the JS-error is slightly different: "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'firePointEvent' of object # is not a function".

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code that you get the error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be solved by defining a specific select state for each series, see http://jsfiddle.net/jZmYW/5/

Thanks to the highcharts support team for helping here.