# Highcharts: Column Chart Select State Fill Color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For the following fiddle, I have used Highcharts CSS Styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/pemxdL6f/

```
.highcharts-point-select {
   stroke: #33ff33;
   stroke-width: 3
}
```

On selecting any column, the fill color defaults to a grey color (#cccccc), which I don't want. The select state fill color should be same as the original color, i.e. fill for select state should not be set. How can I achieve this using CSS Styling?

I don't want to hard code the color in the CSS. Just like in select state options, color can be set to null http://jsfiddle.net/pemxdL6f/6/, can something like this be achieved using CSS Styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer

http://jsfiddle.net/sm57vde9/

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';
.highcharts-point-select {
    stroke: #33ff33 !important;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding a `fill` attribute to your CSS class will do the trick:

```
.highcharts-point-select {
    stroke: #33ff33;
    stroke-width: 3;
    fill: #33ff33;
}
```

Here's a modified version of your fiddle with this change: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/pemxdL6f/5/

You may also find the `states` attribute helpful for a non-CSS solution. See the answer and the included fiddle here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11608259/2596103.

Comment: In my application, the color of columns will be given dynamically by the user. So hard coding color of columns will not work. Is there any other way? Thanks

Comment: Is your application able to use jQuery? You could dynamically alter the CSS properties this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477746/jquery-css-dynamically-change-attributes-of-a-class